# MySQL MIN() limit by column

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL table that is formatted as follows:

```
group_clue:
---------------------------------------------------
| id | group_id | clue_id | completed | run_order |
---------------------------------------------------
|  1 |        1 |       2 |         1 |         1 |
|  2 |        1 |       6 |         1 |         2 |
|  3 |        1 |       4 |         1 |         3 |
|  4 |        1 |       3 |         0 |         4 |
|  5 |        1 |       1 |         0 |         5 |
|  6 |        1 |       5 |         0 |         6 |
|  7 |        2 |       9 |         1 |         1 |
|  8 |        2 |       2 |         0 |         2 |
 ...
---------------------------------------------------
```

The data above in the `group_clue` is constructed such that each `group_id` has every `clue_id` at some `run_order` (ranging from 1 to the number of `clue_id`s and not repeating for a particular group).

**First Question**

I want to create a table showing the first `clue_id` for each `group_id` where `completed = 0` when ordered by `run_order` (aliased as `current_clue`). Using the above example, this would give:

```
---------------------------
| group_id | current_clue |
---------------------------
|        1 |            3 |
|        2 |            2 |
---------------------------
```

My preliminary attempt is:

```
SELECT group_id, MIN(clue_id) as current_clue
FROM group_clue
WHERE completed = 0
GROUP BY group_id
```

However, this returns the same `clue_id` for each `group_id`.

**Second Question**

From the data in the first question, I would like to compose a final table where I GROUP_CONCAT() these results so that it contains every `current_clue` and each `group_id` that contains that `current_clue`. I would also like it ordered from those clues with the most `group_ids` to those with the fewest. An example resulting table is:

```
--------------------
| clue | group_ids |
--------------------
|    3 | 1,5,4,3   |
|    2 | 2,6       |
--------------------
```

I cannot figure out the ordering. My preliminary attempt is:

```
SELECT clue_id, GROUP_CONCAT(group_id)
FROM [resulting_table]
GROUP BY clue_id
ORDER BY [something]
```

Any help is appreciated: what queries would fit this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first part of your question can be solved this way (it expects that `run_order` is unique per group):

```
    SELECT t1.group_id,
           t1.clue_id AS current_clue
      FROM group_clue t1
INNER JOIN (SELECT group_id,
                   MIN(run_order) as run_order
              FROM group_clue
             WHERE completed = 0
          GROUP BY group_id) t2 USING (group_id, run_order)
```

The logic of this query is pretty simple:

1. The inner query selects the pairs of `group_id` and the corresponding minimal value of `run_order` which has the `completed = 0`.
2. After that we join the original table to this set of pairs so that we could select the corresponding `clue_id` additionally.

You can sort by number of elements per group using

```
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

Comment: I don't follow. Could you elaborate?

Comment: You asked how to sort by number of elements in a group. That's what my answer about.

Comment: How does that help? It looks to me like it counts the total number of rows. That's not what I need here.

Comment: @Nathan: it sorts by number of rows, exactly what you asked in "I would also like it ordered from those clues with the most group_ids to those with the fewest."

Comment: @zerkms i guess it should be `MIN(clue_id)` instead of `run_order` and in `USING` part also `clue_id`

Comment: @M Khalid Junaid: nope, it should be `run_order` as per this requirement: Create a table showing the first clue_id for each group_id where completed=0 when ordered by run_order

Comment: @Nathan it is not that hard to spot a typo is it? Fixed it anyway.

Comment: @zerkms My bad! It's going to take me a while to digest that and figure out exactly what that query is doing, so I apologize for not seeing what it's supposed to be. I really appreciate the help!

Comment: @Nathan give me a second to provide an explanation for how the query works.

Comment: You could also use the Pk, as this seems to follow the same order as the clue order

Comment: @Strawberry: that's a fair point and would be a preferred one if it was confirmed.